# How to set relative path for templateUrl in route?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have route rule:

```
.when('/filter-nodes', {
          controller: 'FilterNodesCtrl',
          templateUrl: 'views/filter-nodes.html'
        })
```

How to set path `templateUrl` relative? Sometimes in some pages it does not work:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   angular.js:13642 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: views/filter-nodes.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)

Comment: the path of templateUrl is relative to current file, it does work always - unless there is some typo in path

Comment: So, then I need that template file path will work not only relative current file, always

Comment: yes it should be relative to current file, `webpack` does handle that really well